# spliting the string over separators

Tags: python

can someone please tell me how to fix this? after the last seperator, the code stops and doesn't reach the end of the original string

```
def split_on_separators(original, separators):
    """ (str, str) -> list of str

    Return a list of non-empty, non-blank strings from original,
    determined by splitting original on any of the separators.
    separators is a string of single-character separators.

    >>> split_on_separators("Hooray! Finally, we're done.", "!,")
    ['Hooray', ' Finally', " we're done."]
    """

    result = []
    newstring=''
    for char in original:
        if char in separators:
            result.append(newstring)
            newstring = ""

        else:
            newstring += char
    return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append newstring to result once the loop is completed / before you return. Since there are no separators after the last string it will otherwise never get added since only encountering a separator causes appendage to the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def split_on_separators(original, separators):
    return re.split("[" + separators + "]", original)
```

OK, this isn't perfect because certain characters cannot appear in `separators` because it's used to build a regex, but it works for many cases including the one in the question.  A more robust way would be to simply use `re.split` instead of this function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The code only puts a part of the input string in `result` when it hits a separator.  Since there is no separator at the end of your sample input, the "we're done" in `newstring` is not appended to `result`.  To fix this you would have add an if statement after the for to see if there was something in `newstring`, and then append it if necessary.